# Z-index not adding item to the top

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with z-index.

[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSIr2.png)

As you can see, the dropdown is behind the dropdown element. But dropdown has z-index and position of sticky.

```
          <div className={open ? "dropdown-z-index sticky dropdown container position-absolute end-0 col-md-2 m-2" : "dropdown-out"}>
            <div onClick={closeDropdown} className="dropdown-item cursor-pointer"><BiArrowBack /></div>
            <Link className="unstyled-link dropdown-item" to="/profile"><div onClick={closeDropdown} className="cursor-pointer">Profile</div></Link>
            <Link className="unstyled-link dropdown-item" to="/settings"><div onClick={closeDropdown} className="cursor-pointer">Settings</div></Link> 
          </div>
```

```
.dropdown {
  width: 15%!important;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}


.dropdown-item {
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: none!important;
}

.dropdown-z-index {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: I did not see `position: sticky` in your css code. `z-index` can not be applied to an element that has a `position: static` and by default all elements have `position: static`. Use 

    .dropdown-z-index {
       z-index: 1000;
       position: relative; /* or 'absolute' or 'fixed' to apply z-index
    }


Another possible reason could be your z-index value. Try a higher value. Another possible reason could be that the dropdown element has a parent which has a lower z-index value. Since, you haven't shared the complete html & css of all the elements, it's hard to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: bootstrap is in use too

Comment: You’ll need to share the complete code of the page otherwise it’s just guesswork for anyone else to guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without position, z-index will not work. Use:

```
.dropdown-z-index {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: not working..........

Comment: Can I get the link?

Comment: what link? website is hosted localy

Comment: Add z-index on parent section

Answer (score 0):

for this "dropdown-z-index" class you can give z-index as 9999, if this is not worked then try to add higher z-index than the below image block

Comment: not working......